# How to show Slider dialog widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dialog, slider

Hi im new to flutter and want to make a IconButton that popUp the dialog like the picture, and want to change the contents to the slider.

Example Image

[image]
what widgets should I use?

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with widget.

```dart
class DialogSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const DialogSlider({super.key});

  @override
  State<DialogSlider> createState() => _DialogSliderState();
}

class _DialogSliderState extends State<DialogSlider> {
  double? sliderValue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return StatefulBuilder(
                //to update ui inside dialog
                builder: (context, setStateSB) => AlertDialog(
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text("${sliderValue?.toStringAsFixed(0)}"),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              sliderValue = (sliderValue ?? 0) - 1;
                              if (sliderValue! < 0) {
                                sliderValue = 0;
                              }
                              setStateSB(() {});
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.minimize),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Slider(
                              max: 50,
                              value: sliderValue ?? 0,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setStateSB(() {
                                  sliderValue = value;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              sliderValue = (sliderValue ?? 0) + 1;
                              setStateSB(() {});
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );

          setState(() {}); // if we use inside body;update the UI
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```